# SplashScreen API sometime don't display icon

Tags: android, android-splashscreen

I have `MainActivity` and `LoginActivity`, the `MainActivity` use `Theme.MySplash` (which have blue color and app icon).
At the first launch, the SplashScreen display well (with a background and app icon), However, when I restart the `MainActivity` from `LoginActivity`, the SplashScreen display **without** the app icon.
I restart `MainActivity` instead of back to `MainActivity` because in my real application, I need to recreate `MainActivity`
Here is the demo code

**style.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.MySplash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#00f</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.AndroidSplashScreen12</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.AndroidSplashScreen12" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
</style>
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var keepSplashScreen = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        splashScreen.setKeepVisibleCondition { keepSplashScreen }
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            keepSplashScreen = false
        }, 1500)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_login).setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, LoginActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginActivity**

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_start_main).setOnClickListener {
            finishAffinity()
            startActivity(Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

IF you set icon by Splashscreen API then icon will not show if you start app from android studio. If you open app from phone then icon will start showing.

Comment: Thank you. I see this problem when I start app too but it seem fine for me because it won't affect end user. I have problem with start the MainActivity again from another Activity. I remember I faced this with `beta01` version, I'm not sure it fixed or not in next version.